# Clustering set of points with two different distances

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am working on clustering problem where there are two distances between each pair of points.
For example:

```
dist1(a,b)=.4    
dist2(a,b)=.7
```

There is no simple mapping function that converts those two distances into one distance. Furthermore, I do not have the original attributes of the data(x,y,z  etc... are missing). I just have the two distance matrices.
Is there specific clustering algorithm that deals with these kind of problems? Or how can I convert my problem into normal clustering problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use DBSCAN clustering.

Just use one epsilon for *each* of the two distances.